# is Dependency Injection auto registration considered bad practice?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

Previous to .NET Core I used to use Unity as IOC container which would allow you to auto register classes into IOC Container using Convention over configuration.

With .NET Core, it seems the default IOC container that you're supposed to use doesn't have this feature?

Before I override the default option, and use a 3rd party IOC solution, is there any reason why the standard Dependency Injection framework doesn't have it even as a feature to turn on? Is Autoregistration now considered bad practice and if so, why is it better to specify everything explicitly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In chapter 12 of [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl), [Mark Seemann](https://blog.ploeh.dk/) and I actually state the opposite by saying

> *a DI Container can be either valuable or pointless, depending on how it's used. When it's used in a sufficiently sophisticated way (using Auto-Registration), we consider a DI Container to offer the best value/cost ratio.*

In other words, Auto-Registration is what makes a DI Container useful for  application development.

This message is reflected in one of Mark's old posts, titled [When to use a DI Container](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/). In this article, he shows the following figure to visualize this:

[image: DI registration tradeoffs]

Note that where the figure states "Poor Man's DI", the book now uses the term [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). *Explicit Register* is the model that MS.DI uses and *Convention over Configuration* is basically the same as Auto-Registration.

The reason that the MS.DI container does not have any Auto-Registration functionality, is because this implementation is deliberately left minimal, and is designed especially for the ASP.NET Core framework as its primary consumer. It hasn't been designed with application development in mind. So from that perspective, you can't extrapolate good practices from this ommision.

In the book, we spend a complete section (12.3) on when to use a DI Container and how to use it. You can read that information online [here](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-12/section-12-3), so I won't repeat the reasoning in that complete section. I can also urge you to read chapter 12 completely.

Answer (score 1):

In java-land spring and the jsr dependency injection frameworks have been moving towards auto discovery/registration. I'd say it was the norm now.

Since .net.core has a DI framework built in, I'd avoid using a 3rd party framework just for this.

There are numerous libraries that will handle this for you in .net core. For example:

https://github.com/JonPSmith/NetCore.AutoRegisterDi

https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor

Just pick one you like.

Answer (score -1):

I would not say a bad practice. Rather a choice.

Auto registration require your classes to be somehow discoverable via reflection or implementing interfaces (which will make your code dependent on that interface) and both of those methods leads to a slower resolution than a delegate registration which must be manual, since you have to specify the delegate. how slower ? I use Autofac and [their manual states delegate registrations are 10x faster](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/best-practices/index.html#register-frequently-used-components-with-lambdas).

Also i agree with the accepted answer that wasn't Microsoft purpose to offer a great DI container, but was a great opportunity to force a behavior on the developers. Since chosing this method will help the developers achieve best performance which is critical for a product like asp.net.

Comment: but if it's a web app, wouldn't that performance hit only be starting up the web server and not on each call?

Comment: no, reread what the documentation say: the speed increment is during the resolve, and would especially be seen in something like a web app where on every request you have to resolve everything you need

Comment: Your comment about "their manual states manual registrations are 10x faster" seems to be quoted out of context. The Autofac manual states that a registration using *a lambda* is 10x faster than registration using a type. Whether or not you use type or lambda registration is something different than Auto-Registration vs. Explicit Registration. Both Auto-Registration and Explicit registration are typically applied by registering types. The performance difference between Auto-Registratin and Explicit Registration is not a simple factor; it will depend on the application at hand.

Comment: ok that is because autofac supports all kind of registrations. microsoft need and explicit registration in order to have a delegate (or lambda registration) which is fast, so it is a requirement to have a fast resolve